# Passing specific properties to each view instance in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

Is there a way of binding specific properties to each instance of a child vue component in a `v-for`loop?

For example, consider the following vueify component:

```
<template>
    ...
    <div class="cal-body">
        <div v-for="week in weeksInMonth">
            <cal-week class='cal-week' :weekdata="events-week$index" :events="events"></cal-week>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        ...
        computed:{
            return {
                events-week1:[
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ],
                events-week2:[
                    {...},
                    {...}
                ]
            }
        }        
    }
</script>
```

In this example, the template is for a calendar where each week component is a child of the current component.

I know I could have an `events` computed or data property and pass it in, but I'd like to pass only the events that belong in the specific week.

I've tried this below and it doesn't work and I can't find a way to do it in the documentation.

Is there a way to do this? If not, what's the alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your events-week form computed data to data and store them in an array like

```
data: function(){
   return {
      events: {
         'events-week1':[
            {...},
            {...}
         ],
         'events-week2':[
            {...},
            {...}
         ]
      }
   }
```

When looping you can then

```
<div v-for="week in weeksInMonth">
   <cal-week class='cal-week' :weekdata="events['events-week' + $index]"  :events="events"></cal-week>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, that did it. Thanks for the help!